# The values are not being passed on the first click of editText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I need to take the values of a and b from the user via editText and pass it to the next activity.This is the first activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class activitysecond extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] arraySpinner;
    private String[] arraySpinner2;
    int a=0,b=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
        final EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Button EnterButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Enterbutton);

        this.arraySpinner = new String[]{
                "None", "Lightly Active", "Moderately Active", "Very Active"
        };
                Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
                (this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arraySpinner
                );

        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        this.arraySpinner2 = new String[]{
                "Male", "Female"
        };

                Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>
                (this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arraySpinner2
                );
        s1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
                bundle.putInt("one",a);
            }

        });

        editText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
                bundle.putInt("two",b);
            }

        });

        EnterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);
                startActivity(z);
                z.putExtras(bundle);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The next activity to which i want to pass the values is

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activitythird extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.thirdactivity);

}

public void thirdbutton(View view){
    final TextView thirdtext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.thirdtext);

    Bundle seconddata=getIntent().getExtras();
    int vala=seconddata.getInt("one");
    int valb=seconddata.getInt("two");

    thirdtext.setText(vala + " " +valb);


}
```

}

The values a and b are not passed and the thirdtext does not change
Please help!!

Comment: you set extras after start activity: startActivity(z);  z.putExtras(bundle); try putExtra() before startActivity()

Answer (score 1):

You start your activity before you add the bundle to your intent.

Try it like this:

```
Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);
z.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ClickListener` for the edit texts and add the following lines in `onClick` of EnterButton

```
  a = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
  bundle.putInt("one",a);
  b = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
  bundle.putInt("two",b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
EnterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);
        startActivity(z);
        z.putExtras(bundle);
    }
});
```

with

```
EnterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);
        z.putExtras("one", Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString()));
        z.putExtras("two", Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(z);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the below; putExtra comes before startActivity, that is the mistake.

```
EnterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);
            startActivity(z);
            z.putExtras(bundle);
        }
    });
```

try at below code;

```
EnterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);

            z.putExtras(bundle); // first
            startActivity(z); //second
        }
    });
```

Also editText onClickListeners should not be implemented for your case. You should get the variables via:

```
if (editText1.getText() != null) { // to avoid exception
    a = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
    bundle.putInt("one",a);
}
if (editText2.getText() != null) { to avoid exception
    b = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
    bundle.putInt("two",b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
EnterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent z = new Intent(activitysecond.this, activitythird.class);
                z.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(z);
            }
        });
```

`z.putExtras(bundle);` must be higher that `startActivity(z);`